# C# Merge 2 objects of the same with linq 2 object

Tags: c#, linq, merge

```
public class SomePropertyClass{
    public string VarA{get;set;}
    public string VarB{get;set;}
}

SomePropertyClass v1 = new SomePropertyClass(){VarA = "item 1"};
SomePropertyClass v2 = new SomePropertyClass(){VarB = "item 2"};
```

Is it possible to create a third variable that will have:

v3: VarA = "item 1",VarB = "item 2"

I mean, I want to merge objects with linq to object.

**Edit**
for now i need from the same type. but it would be nice in the future to merge by property name.

I have an account model with a lot of properties that the user input in step 1.
I want to merge this half full model with step 2 half full model.

**Edit 2**

```
//step 1
        GlobalOnBoardingDataModel step1= (GlobalOnBoardingDataModel)HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionVariableNameStepOne];
//step 2           
        GlobalOnBoardingDataModel step2 = (GlobalOnBoardingDataModel)HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionVariableNameStepTwo];



     class GlobalOnBoardingDataModel {
        public string Email;//step 1
        public string Name;//step 1
        public string Phone;//step2
        public string Address;//step2
        }
    }
```

thanks

Comment: `var v3 = new SomePropertyClass { VarA = v1.VarA, VarB = v2.VarB };` ? Why would you want to use LINQ ?

Comment: Help us understand more about your use case. Will you always have exactly two objects, one with VarA set and one with VarB set?

Comment: Then please give us a full example!

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea? It looks like you would be much better off by simply storing 1 object in the session, and write to one subset of the properties during "step1" and another subset during "step2".

Comment: @JonasH, MVC is de-serializing it, it means that I need to join them, I cannot tell mvc to de-serialize over an existing object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to accomplish this using reflection:

```
public class SomePropertyClass
{
    public string VarA { get; set; }
    public string VarB { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomePropertyClass v1 = new SomePropertyClass() { VarA = "item 1" };
        SomePropertyClass v2 = new SomePropertyClass() { VarB = "item 2" };

        var yo = v1.Combine(v2);
    }

    static public IEnumerable<object> Combine<T, U>(this T one, U two)
    {
        var properties1 = one.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.GetValue(one, null) != null).Select(p => p.GetValue(one, null));
        var properties2 = two.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.GetValue(two, null) != null).Select(p => p.GetValue(two, null));

        return new List<object>(properties1.Concat(properties2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed answer to use reflection in order to provided an auto mechanism.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the answer to the OP's question which is:

- an exact answer
- for two objects of the same type

  - *(for two objects of different types the code would be almost identical)*
- a solution that is not hard coded
- using linq
- that respects non-nullity of source values
- that doesn't need an external library
- in one line of code.

```cs
public static T Merge<T>(T target, T source)
{
  typeof(T)
  .GetProperties()
  .Select((PropertyInfo x) => new KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, object>(x, x.GetValue(source, null)))
  .Where((KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, object> x) => x.Value != null).ToList()
  .ForEach((KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, object> x) => x.Key.SetValue(target, x.Value, null));

  //return the modified copy of Target
  return target;
}
```

Comment: @A1rPun, I guess `return target;` is a line of code. So, one pretty line of code ಠ‿ಠ

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this ... a Merge method that takes whichever value is not null from the matching properties?

```
public class SomePropertyClass{
    public string VarA{get;set;}
    public string VarB{get;set;}

    public SomePropertyClass Merge (SomePropertyClass other)
    {
       return new SomePropertyClass 
                    { VarA = this.VarA ?? other.VarA, 
                      VarB = this.VarB ?? other.VarB 
                    };
    }
```

If you wanted a solution that would work for *any* class you'd need to use reflection to find all the properties and then copy the missing ones.
    }

Comment: So there is no other cleaver auto-something that merge it? (-: ?

Comment: Not built in, you'll need to use reflection or some library like http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/